# Convert image with LiipImagineBundle

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I try to convert a image with the LiipImagineBundle. The file is stored in a subfolder `storage/` in the symfony app root folder and not in the `web/` folder. This is because I have to wite a custom security layer before the delivery of the images.

For example I have a image in the folder `symfony_app/storage/images/image.jpg`. Now I want to convert it and save the filtered image in the subfolder `symfony_app/storage/images/thumbnail/image.jpg`.

Now I try the code

```
$imagineController = $this->container->get('liip_imagine.controller');
$imagineController->filterAction(new Request(), '/path/to/symfony_app/storage/images/image.jpg', 'thumbnail');
```

but I get an 404 error with the message `"Source image could not be found"`.

I don't understand why the file could not be found. I also tried the console command

```
php bin/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve images/image.jpg
```

and get the result:

```
[Imagine\Exception\RuntimeException]
Unable to open image /path/to/symfony_app/storage/images/image.jpg
```

The `storage/` subfolder has the access rights 777 and this is my LiipImagine configuration:

```
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root: /var/www/actus-backend/storage/
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        thumbnail:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: 777 sounds wrong to me. As that is below the webroot I can imagine that some software is blocking access to these files. Check with your system documentation about restrictions next to traditonal Unix permissions.

Comment: I know that 777 isn't the best idea and I want to change this in the future. The app is on my own ubuntu server. There are no other restrictions, but the app is running in a docker container. May this be the problem?

Comment: The docker container might have different paths, that could be the culprit.

Comment: What are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I'm using Nginx. I pushed now my code on another test server without docker. There is the same problem.

Comment: You have to check `php extension imagick or gd`

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your storage path using the `kernel.root_dir` parameter.

If you need the path to the secure images folder in your security layer it may be helpful to define it as parameter. Reuse that parameter in the configuration for the LiipImagine bundle:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    images_root_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../storage"

liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root: "%images_root_dir%"
```